# extjs 4 getRowClass changes not visible

Tags: html, extjs4

I've the following viewconfig applied to the grid panel. It is supposed to change the row colour based on a datavalue, but the changes are not visible on the view.

```
.changed_colour {
    background-color: #FFCC00
}

viewConfig: {
    //Return CSS class to apply to rows depending upon data values
    getRowClass: function (row, index) {
        var data = row.data;
        return data.NoteType === 'PRIVATE' ? 'changed_colour' : ''; 
    }
}
```

I notice the style being applied for the row in Firebug:

```
<tr class="x-grid-row changed_colour"> 

.x-grid-row .x-grid-cell {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #FAFAFA #EDEDED #EDEDED;
    border-right: 0 solid #EDEDED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    font: 11px tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

The above style snippet belongs to Extjs. Can anybody suggest a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the color is set on the grid cell. You can see it in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. To make it work, change your style to:

```
.changed_colour .x-grid-cell {
    background-color: #FFCC00
}
```

Comment: 2 years after the answer was posted ... was useful for me as well :)